# Express.JS API with Node.JS app issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I'm trying to create a REST API in Express.js but I have some issues, **I hope that somebody can help me** )

my Express.js code:

```
router.get('/apps/download/:downloadId', function (req, res, next) {
    const opts = Object.assign({downloadId: req.params.downloadId}, req.query);
      gplay.download(opts)
      .then(res.json)
      .catch(next);
  });
```

My Node.js app jQuery code is:

```
const data = $( '.row' ).eq( 6 ).find( 'table tr' ).map( function() {
    const a = $( this ).find( 'td:first-child a' );
    const td = $( this ).find( 'td:last-child' );

    return {
        version: a.text(),
        href: a.attr( 'href' ),
        date: td.text()
    }
}).get();

console.log( data )

const sdata = $( '.row' ).eq( 7 ).find( 'table tr' ).map( function() {
    const a = $( this ).find( 'td:first-child a' );
    const td = $( this ).find( 'td:last-child' );

    return {
        version: a.text(),
        href: a.attr( 'href' ),
        date: td.text()
    }
}).get();

console.log( sdata )
```

So when I open `'/apps/download/:downloadId'` in the browser it gives me only console.log:

```
[
]

[
    {
         version: '1.0.2',
         href: '/download-app/com.playgendary.kickthebuddy/5_com.playgendary.kickthebuddy_2018-06-09.apk/',
         date: 'June 9, 2018'
    },

    {
         version: '1.0.1',
         href: '/download-app/com.playgendary.kickthebuddy/4_com.playgendary.kickthebuddy_2018-05-28.apk/',
         date: 'May 28, 2018'
    },

    {
         version: 'Varies with device',
         href: '/download-app/com.playgendary.kickthebuddy/5_com.playgendary.kickthebuddy_2018-05-22.apk/',
         date: 'May 22, 2018'
    }
]
```

However, in the tab browser i get only clear window:

[Image of Clear window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IoWk.jpg)

Console.log result:

[console.log screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9m1C.jpg)

*So I need to get all of this data in REST API on the page in JSON, so what should I do?*

Comment: It's very confusing what you're trying to do on your `Node.js app jQuery code`, also what's the function definition of: `gplay.download` ?  I don't see it defined anywhere, neither do I know what you're doing with it's opts parameter

Comment: `gplay.download` thats how i call module export in my app, and get data from it to my api